# How to make a global <b:includable> in Blogger?

Tags: xml, blogger

I am wondering how to add a `<b:includable>` outside of `<b:widget>` and `<b:section>` in a Blogger template.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the link shared in `Abdelnaem Atia`'s answer.

Firstly you need to define the `b:includable` in the template (best would be within `<head>` region) -

```
<b:defaultmarkups>
    <b:defaultmarkup type='Common'>
        <b:includable id='TestContent'>
            Content I am including
        </b:includable>
    </b:defaultmarkup>
</b:defaultmarkups>
```

The type is set to `Common` so that it can be referenced from anywhere in the template. Now you will have simply reference using `b:include` -

```
<b:include name='TestContent' />
```

You can create as many `b:includable` as you require within the Common type `b:defaultmarkup` tag -

```
<b:defaultmarkups>
    <b:defaultmarkup type='Common'>
        <b:includable id='TestContent'>
            Content I am including
        </b:includable>
        <b:includable id='MoreContent'>
            More Content I am including
        </b:includable>
    </b:defaultmarkup>
</b:defaultmarkups>
```

This functionality was introduced in the `v3` template engine ( https://blogger.googleblog.com/2017/03/share-your-unique-style-with-new.html ) in Blogger but now works with older `v2` templates as well

Answer (score 2):

Hello bro use this url .. 
https://bloggercode-blogconnexion.blogspot.com.eg/2017/05/tag-b-defaultmarkups.html
(Abdelnaem Atia)

Comment: Can't understand the language :(

Answer (score 0):

> Includes are most useful if you have a section of code that you want
>   to re-use in several different places, or only include in certain
>   circumstances.
>
> To do this, write the content inside a `b:includable`, then use
>   `b:include` wherever you want it to appear.

Source: [Widget Tags for Layouts](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en&ref_topic=6321969)